# WCF Derived types and violation of the Open/Closed principle

Tags: wcf, derived-class, known-types, open-closed-principle

I have a base class that I use in WCF service calls,

```
[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedClass))]
public abstract class MyBaseClass {
   //some properties
}
```

I derive from it and every time I derive I have to add the `[KnownType(typeof(MyDerivedClass))]` attribute and every time I do I violate the [Open/Closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) principle. Is there anyway to derive classes like this for use in WCF and not have to add attributes to the parent class each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static method which will return known types :

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownType")]
public class MyBaseClass
{
    //some properties

    private static Type[] GetKnownType()
    {
        return KnownTypesHelper.GetKnownTypes<MyBaseClass>();
    }
}
```

Now create a static class KnownTypesHelper that will return an array of known types (by scanning assemblies to find implementations of base class for example...)